# Pages of an asp.net application is not rendering properly

Tags: asp.net

I need some help to understand why my application(developed in asp.net 2.0) pages not rendering properly in one of my client machine, however for others it is working properly.
On looking at the screen shot my client sends me I found that the css and javascript files are not loading properly.
Do any one have any idea why this is happening at that perticular users end and how to solve this problem.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="ValuatorMaster.master.cs"
Inherits="Proof.ValuatorMaster" %>
<asp:literal id="ltDocType" runat="server"></asp:literal>
<html>
<head runat="server">
  <script src="impact/Impact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Proof.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
  <link href="Proof.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/impact/Impact.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Master Page</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Also which browser is the user using?

Comment: Please provide more information regarding why the resources didn't load: 404s?

Comment: Why not post the screenshot as well?

Comment: It is not possible to post the full code but below is the master page formating:

Comment: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="ValuatorMaster.master.cs"     Inherits="Proof.ValuatorMaster" %>
<asp:literal id="ltDocType" runat="server"></asp:literal>
<html ><head runat="server">
    <script src="impact/Impact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Proof.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
    <link href="Proof.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/impact/Impact.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Master Page</title>
</head>

Comment: The user getting this formating issue in bothe the browser IE6 and in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to login to use the site? 
Are the css files in a secure area and the user not logged in? (this can happen on login pages I have found)

Comment: No, if windows authentication is enabled in the system then it asks for the username and password, however if user disabled windows authentication then it won't. And one poin that only one user is getting this formating not all the users.